# Error converting a NSString to a NSURL

Tags: macos, nsurl, data-conversion

The following snippet produces the debugger listing that follows it.  Yet, if Line Two replaces Line One, there is no error. LineTwo was obtained by coping and pasting the debugger output from a previous run.  Can you explain this to me?

```
//LINE ONE
NSString* aString = self.urlText;
NSLog(@"aString: %@",aString);
//LINE TWO
//NSString* aString = @"file:///Users/oldmancoyote1/Documents/A%20REFERENCE%20SYSTEM/C/Computers/iOS/C%20and%20Obj.%20C/C%20Language/1-4.6.html";
NSURL* testURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:aString];
```

2016-01-03 12:44:30.307 webScrol[1505:62452] aString: file:///Users/oldmancoyote1/Documents/A%20REFERENCE%20SYSTEM/C/Computers/iOS/C%20and%20Obj.%20C/C%20Language/1-4.6.html

2016-01-03 12:44:30.307 webScrol[1505:62452] -[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000a4800

2016-01-03 12:44:30.307 webScrol[1505:62452] Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): -[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000a4800

Comment: My immediate guess is, `self.urlText` is not actually an `NSString`, but rather an `NSURL`, and when you pass it to `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`, that method tries to treat it as an `NSString` (e.g. by calling `length` on it) causing the crash.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of `self.urlText`? Does it have type `id` by any chance?

Comment: @property NSString* urlText;  Value of urlText was initially defined as a NSString*, archived and unarchived using encodeObject:forKey: and decodeObjectForKey:
I think I have checked all this.  No doubt I've made some mistake, but I can't find it!

Comment: Jasper is obviously correct with his comment.  It looks like you've assigned an `NSURL` instance to `self.urlText` and not an `NSString`.

Comment: @CarlCarlson can you show us the code that assigns `urlText`?

Comment: Original source: @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* url;  [aCoder encodeObject:self.url forKey:@"url"];  _url = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"url"];  Object: Model: unarchives then     self.currentSource = [self.sourceLib lastObject];
final object:     self.currentSource = self.model.currentSource;
    self.urlText = self.currentSource.url;

Comment: How is `self.url` defined?

Comment: In the original object: @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* url;
Xcode think self.urlText is a NSString* as shown here:_currentSource Source * 0x600000031620 0x0000600000031620
NSObject NSObject  
_url NSString * 0x6000000a3120 0x00006000000a3120

Comment: Well, it seems very clear to me that `aString` is an `NSURL` from the error you’re getting. You could log `NSStringFromClass([aString class])` to be sure. If you want a definitive answer here I think you’ll need to provide all the relevant code rather than just a snippet.

Comment: Jasper:  Thank you for your effort on this.  I think the problem stems from the line in Apple's documentation for NSOpenPanel which defines the function URLs as "Returns an array containing the absolute paths of the selected files and directories as URLs."  By "paths" and "URLs" I think they actually meant an array of NSURs not paths.  I assumed paths meant NSString paths and copied the value to an NSString.

Comment: It is defined in the documentation as an array of NSURL objects: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSOpenPanel/URLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aString` is actually an `NSURL` object despite being stored in an `NSString` variable. This must have happened in earlier code than what you have provided.

When it’s passed to `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`, that function tries to treat it as an `NSString` by calling its `length` method and the program crashes.